# Ansible azure_rm_postgresqlconfiguration_info The error was: AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, ansible

I am using Python version 3.8.2 and Ansible 2.9.19 and I get an error while using `azure_rm_postgresqlconfiguration_info` Ansible module:

> ...  The error was: AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'...
> ... AnsiballZ_azure_rm_postgresqlconfiguration_info.py", line 102, in  ...

I already read about that deprecation in Python versions higher than 3.7, but is there any way to upgrade `azure_rm_postgresqlconfiguration_info` module? Or something else?

Or downgrading for Python 3.7 is only one way to work with `azure_rm_postgresqlconfiguration_info`?

Comment: The [relevant issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/139) alleges to have been closed in 2020, so if you're still experiencing that you can file a regression